# Gurobi with C++

Tags: gurobi, c++

This is not the right question to be posting here, but is anywhere a video tutorial/ written on how to link C++ header files with Gurobi?

Comment: Have you checked the tutorials by Gurobi? If you're using Windows, https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360032925011-How-do-I-build-C-C-projects-on-Windows-

Comment: I don't know whether this exists, but I do think that the question is in the scope of the website

Comment: I've found this article really useful as depending on the compiler, you may need to rebuild the Gurobi libraries: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039093112-How-do-I-resolve-undefined-reference-errors-while-linking-Gurobi-in-C- 
Can you run the standard C++ examples (provided under the folder where you installed Gurobi)?

Comment: Also, if you're using CMake, you can use this to find the header files and libraries: https://gist.github.com/torressa/27efc65710a6d5948fbf649a419af300 
Then you can use it like any other CMake package `target_link_libraries(my_package PUBLIC GUROBI::GUROBI)`

Comment: Thanks @NaraBegnini and @DavidTorres! I am running it on MacOS. I am unable to run the examples provided under the folder where Gurobi is installed.

Comment: That's probably a good start then, there's a Makefile under the `<installdir>/examples/build/` with targets to run only the C++ examples (`make run_c++`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On macOS, you can find a Makefile inside `/Library/gurobi950/macos_universal2/examples/build` to compile all examples. Open the Terminal.app and enter the following:

```bash
# change the directory
cd /Library/gurobi950/macos_universal2/examples/build

# compile and run all c++ examples
make run_c++
```

This will compile and run all c++ examples. If you want to compile a specific c++ example, you only need to include the gurobi header and link to the gurobi library. Let's take `mip1_c++.cpp` as an example and let's take the `clang++` compiler:

```bash
# define bash variable for Gurobi's path
GUROBI_HOME="/Library/gurobi950/macos_universal2/"

# change the directory
cd $GUROBI_HOME/examples/c++

# Compile the program
clang++ mip1_c++.cpp -I${GUROBI_HOME}/include/ -L${GUROBI_HOME}/lib -lgurobi_c++ -lgurobi95 -o mip1_c++
```

Then you can execute the program inside the Terminal.app by `./mip1_c++`. Last but not least, if you're working with C++, it's highly recommended to make yourself familiar with Makefile-Generator tools like CMake.

Comment: Thanks a ton, Joni! Indeed, I am trying to figure out C++ with optimisation softwares. But, I must say it is quite a maze. Would you know of any resources to aid me?

Answer (score 6):

There is a dedicated section about [C++ programming with Gurobi in the official documentation](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/quickstart_mac/cpp_interface.html#section:C++).

There is also a [CMake example in the Gurobi Knowledge Base](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039499751-How-do-I-use-CMake-to-build-Gurobi-C-C-projects-).

Comment: Thanks, Matt. Apologise for bother here as well as on Gurobi thread. I was struggling, a bit.